# Nested RecyclerView's notifyDataSetChanged() is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a `Nested Recycler View`.

The `nested recycler` view is dynamically added for each item when the button is clicked.

I have implemented this function. But when you click the button to add an item,

the item update is only possible through the `nested recyclerview's  setAdapter()`,

not the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Why is this happening? Why isn't it updated with `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

At least as far as I know the `setAdapter()` should only be called once.

Does it matter if the `setAdapter()` is called multiple times?

What I want is to be updated by the `notifyDataSetChanged()`, not an `setAdapter()`.

But item is updated by the `setAdapter()`.

Why?

**RoutineModel.java**

```
public class RoutineModel {
    String routine;
    public ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> arrayListDetail;

    public RoutineModel(String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
    }

    public String getRoutine() {
        return routine;
    }
}
```

**RoutineAdapter.java** **(Nested Recyclerview's Adapter)**

```
public class RoutineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<RoutineModel> routineItems = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public void addItem(RoutineModel item) {
        routineItems.add(item);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoutineModel curRoutineItem = routineItems.get(position);
        holder.setItems(curRoutineItem);

        // Set Routine Detail (Nested RecyclerView)
        holder.setRoutineDetailRecyClerView();
        RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter();
        curRoutineItem.arrayListDetail = new ArrayList<>();
        curRoutineItem.arrayListDetail.add(new RoutineDetailModel());

        holder.routine_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
        detailAdapter.addItems(curRoutineItem.arrayListDetail);

        // add NestedRecyclerView's item (Dynamically)
        holder.addSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                curRoutineItem.arrayListDetail.add(new RoutineDetailModel());
                detailAdapter.addItems(curRoutineItem.arrayListDetail);
                holder.routine_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter); // HERE!!!!!
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return routineItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView routine;
        Button addSet;
        RecyclerView routine_detail;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            initViews();
        }

        private void initViews() {
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine);
            routine_detail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_routine);
            addSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_set);

        }
        private void setItems(RoutineModel routineItem) {
            routine.setText(routineItem.getRoutine());
        }
        public void setRoutineDetailRecyClerView() {
            routine_detail.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
            routine_detail.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**RoutineDetailModel.java** **(Nested Recyclerview's Model)**

```
public class RoutineDetailModel {
    String set;
    String weight;
    String reps;
}
```

**RoutineDetailAdapter.java**

```
public class RoutineDetailAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineDetailAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItems(ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> getItem() {
        return this.items;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_detail_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoutineDetailModel item = items.get(position);
        holder.setItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView set;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            set = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
        }

        private void setItem(RoutineDetailModel item) {
            set.setText("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**OnCreateViewHolder**

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter();
        holder.setRoutineDetailRecyClerView();
        holder.routine_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);

        return holder;
    }
```

Comment: Hello ybybyb. I think you try to notifyDataSetChanged() with `addItems(ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> items)`?

Comment: Yes, because I think the `recycler view` should be updated every time an item is added...

Is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecyclerView`s work by recycling a handful of `ViewHolder` objects, and updating them to display a different item's data. That happens in `onBindViewHolder`, which is where you're setting it up to display the data with your `holder.setItems(curRoutineItem)` call, right?

But each time you bind a view holder, this is what you're doing:

- getting the `RoutineModel` for the current position
- clearing its `arrayListDetail` and adding a single, new ``RoutineDetailModel```
- creating a new `RoutineDetailAdapter` which only contains that single `RoutineDetailModel`, and setting that on the `ViewHolder`'s `RecyclerView`, replacing what was already there
- adding a click listener that adds another `RoutineDetailModel` to the `RoutineModel` and adapter (both of which will be cleared and recreated next time `onBindViewHolder` is called)

So I don't know specifically where your problem lies, but you're not actually storing this state with the added items - it gets wiped every time `onBindViewHolder` is called, whenever an item scrolls into view.

If you're saying that you click the button and nothing happens in the `RecyclerView` without calling `setAdapter` again, then I'm not sure why that would happen - at that point `detailAdapter` is referencing the adapter in the recycler view, and you are adding another item (technically replacing its items with the same list of one plus another one).

But if you mean you scroll the list and your items disappear, yeah that's going to happen, because you delete them every time the item scrolls back into view. This stuff looks like data initialisation:

```
curRoutineItem.arrayListDetail = new ArrayList<>();
curRoutineItem.arrayListDetail.add(new RoutineDetailModel());
```

and definitely shouldn't be happening in `onBindViewHolder`. This stuff:

```
RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter();
holder.routine_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
```

is `RecyclerView` initialisation and should probably be happening once per recyclerview, in `onViewHolderCreated`. Then in `onBindViewHolder` you can just call `getAdapter` and set the items you want to display.

That might help you with your issue, I'm not sure what you're seeing exactly because I'd expect it to feel pretty broken as it is!

Comment: i moved `RoutineDetailAdapter detailAdapter = new RoutineDetailAdapter();` and  `holder.routine_detail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);` to `onCreateViewHolder`, But it doesn't work..

Comment: Then, do you mean you have to keep `adapter` to solve this problem?

Comment: You have a handful of ``ViewHolder``s, enough to fill the visible part of the list - the system creates them by calling ``onCreateViewHolder``. Each ``ViewHolder`` has its own ``RecyclerView``, and each of those has its own ``Adapter``. You can set that adapter in ``onCreateViewHolder``, when it's all being set up. ``onBindViewHolder`` is called when you want to display data in a list item, using the ``ViewHolder`` the system gives you. So to display your data in its ``RecyclerView``, you need to get its adapter and set the items, and do ``notifyDataSetChanged()`` (which you are)

Comment: I don't know if that will fix your specific problem, but think of each adapter as a thing that slots into a ``RecyclerView`` to make it display stuff, and you create and set one whenever you set up the ``RecyclerView``, when your ``ViewHolder`` is created. Then you can just update it with the current data, same as how you set ``someTextView.text = whatever``. But remember, you keep resetting your ``ArrayList``s (the actual data you're holding) in ``onBindViewHolder``, so your items will keep getting reset when they scroll off screen (well technically when they scroll back into view)

Comment: English is difficult for me, so it's a bit difficult to understand, but each `ViewHolder` should have its own` ReclerView` and its own `Adapter`, right?
Because as you said, I called `setAdapter()`and `setRoutineDetailRecyClerView()` `(setLayoutManager..etc)` in `onCreateiViewHolder` and it  worked similarly.

Comment: oh..i found problem right now..No matter which recyclerview's button is clicked, the item is added to the last recyclerview. But I want to add an item in the recycler view corresponding to each button.
At this time, the button is the button on the outer recycler view. 
Should I implement it in onCreateViewHolder so that button events can be handled for each recycler view too?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's hard to explain in comments! Your ``ViewHolder`` *has* a ``RecyclerView``, it's inflated from the layout - you're just creating an adapter for it during the setup (in ``onCreateViewHolder``). You need to create a new one each time, because each ``ViewHolder`` has its own ``RecyclerView`` which needs its own ``Adapter``. If you set the same adapter instance on every ``RecyclerView``, they'll all display the same thing. It's hard to give advice without seeing what your code looks like now though

Comment: I added the modified `onCreateViewHolder` code. Can you see that, plz?
By doing it in onCreateViewHolder, each viewholder has a RecyclerView and an Adapter.
Is that right what you said?

Comment: Yeah, each ``ViewHolder`` is just a layout to display an item's data. Your XML has a ``RecyclerView`` in it, so when you inflate that layout for the `ViewHolder`, that's one of the views (which you assign as `routine_detail` in `initViews()`. So each `RecyclerView` needs an adapter (or it won't do anything). Once you've `set` it, you should `get` it in `onBindViewHolder`. Then you can do `setItems` with the `arrayListDetail` for the current item (from `position`). I can't really tell you much more than that, I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, I'm just showing you how it generally works!

Comment: Thank you.I understand more and more.
However Is Adapter also needed for each ViewHodolder like RecyclerView?

Comment: Each ``RecyclerView`` needs its own ``Adapter`` - the adapter controls what it displays. If you create one adapter and set it on every ``RecyclerView``, they'll all display the same thing. That's why you need a separate one for each ``RecyclerView``, so each ``ViewHolder`` creates one and adds it to its ``RecyclerView``

Comment: Okay thanks, but I'll just ask one more question. In my problem, the reason why setAdapter() is called from onCreateViewHolder() rather than from onBindViewHolder() is because setAdapter only needs to be called once per RecyclerView(per layout)?
If i call setAdapter() in onBindViewHolder(), is it because it is called every time data is bound?

Comment: Yeah exactly :) like I said it probably won't fix your issue, but you were creating a new adapter every time the data was bound (when an item scrolled into view), and since you're clearing your arraylist too, you're losing any data that was already stored in that adapter. Your problem is probably related to clearing the arraylist (you're losing all the stuff you're adding with the button) but creating new adapters constantly is going to produce bugs and performance issues too

Comment: That's why `setAdapter()` is called only once.
I think I know a little now.
Thank you so much for helping me with detailed answers from yesterday.
Really realy thank you so much..  :)